# Android: close application after the user pressed back or home

Tags: android, settings, manifest

I wrote and application with basically just a scrollview which launches in < 1.5 seconds, and it includes a FAQ. Now I added this application to my settings, by adding a shorcut:
`<header android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_support" android:title="@string/settings_support">
        <intent android:targetPackage="com.jader.xperiaguides" android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN" android:targetClass="com.jader.xperiaguides.MainActivity" />
    </header>`
Now, when I press this shortcut, everything works well, but as the usual android behavior works - android is caching the application into the ram. More than > 8 mb used by pressing that option, until the lmk ends it.
The app is launching really fast anyway, so I just would like to disable android from caching it into ram, so it doesn't run in background and needs to be restarted everytime you use the app.
Sorry for my maybe imperfect english, I'm 14 and english isn't my native language.
I hope you can help!
Jan

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `android:noHistory` setting for your activity in the [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file. If this setting is `true`, whenever the user navigates away from your activity, it will be finished. This means android will not keep a back stack of your activity in current task, when it goes to the background. Using your own words, it will no longer be "cached in ram".

Full reference is available [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Example of how to set this in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity 
    android:name="MyActivity" 
    android:noHistory="true">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

To close your application when user clicks back button, or when app is in the background:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    finish();
}
```

That way then app is not in the foreground it will be actually closed. Hope this helps.